# Nginx config for NGG / NextGen Gallery

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery, nginx

I run wordpress on nginx + php-fpm in a subfolder `abc`. I want to upload images into a [NextgenGallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and the ajax-based uploader yields this:

```
POST 404 for http://example.com/abc/index.php/photocrati_ajax
```

Obviously the rewrite in the `nginx.conf` does not work. Here are the relevant parts of it:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files                $uri =404;
     fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_pass             php-fpm;
     fastcgi_index            index.php;
}
```

So, how to serve `photocrati_ajax` via nginx and make the uploads work?

Answer (score 0):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Worked for me. Otherwise `POST` requests were missing the `action` parameter, whyever.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying many configs and found answer:

1. install plugin Nginx-helper (nginx in embedded search)
2. enable permalink in settings (any)
3. optionality configure nginx with this manual http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx
   ....

PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

404 error with Nginx, wordpress, Nextgengallery

It is problem with permalinks, the above suggestion works with one addition you have to disable and then enable the permalinks.

1)  Install Nginx-helper
2)  disable permalinks and save.
3)  enable permalinks and save.

Once you can upload photos with nextgen, Nginx-helper is no longer needed. You can disable and remove it.